# Error opening device /dev/video0: video capture not supported

Tags: camera, usb-power, raspberry-pi-os-buster

1. I am trying to set up USb camera with RPi4. It is working well with PC windows10 default 'camera' application but failed with RPi4. I use mjpg-streamer to access the streaming.

   /usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -f 15 -r 640x480"  -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www"

**error:**

```
MJPG Streamer Version: git rev: 310b29f4a94c46652b20c4b7b6e5cf24e532af39
 i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0
 i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
 i: Frames Per Second.: 15
 i: Format............: JPEG
 i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT
Error opening device /dev/video0: video capture not supported.
Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
 i: init_VideoIn failed
```

when plug the USB camera to Rpi4, it shows this log. not sure, this is the cause of not working...

```
raspberrypi kernel: [  761.729856] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle
```

lsusb give me this...

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

2. Also, when I unplug the USB cam from RPi4, it doesn't delete the 'video0' from /dev/video*
3. When i give 'sudo reboot' it shutdown RPi4 instead of rebooting it. For reboot, i need to power OFF and ON manually. Before camera error it was working well, properly rebooting according to the command but suddenly not.

How should I resolve these issues?

Comment: have you tried using `sudo` - perhaps it's a simple permission issue. Also, add the result of `lsusb` to your question, perhaps the USB device isn't fully supported

Comment: yes, tried with 'sudo' too but same error.
Updated question with lsusb result.

Comment: so, it isn't even recognised as an USB device

Comment: yes, seems. but then its strange that its well detected at windows pc 'camera' app but not on RPi4.

Comment: @Bravo Not sure, but does it make any sense...(when i plug-in usb to RPi4)
raspberrypi kernel: [  761.729856] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle

Comment: I remember some USB cameras (and other devices) in the past simply would not work in linux - though, not being detected at all is odd - what's the make/model of the camera (according to windows)

Comment: Its Arducam IMX291.
Also i see /dev/video0 always, doesn't matter if the camera is plugged in or not?
Isn't this strange?

Comment: I see plenty of /dev/video* devices and have no cameras at all

Comment: yes but /dev/video0 is the most first detectable device which can be considered as plug-in device. but when it should be plug-out /dev/video0 should not be there in list, but others like video10,11,12,13,,,,etc could be still thre.

Comment: oh, right - that is odd ... so even when you reboot `/dev/video0` is still there?

Comment: yes, its always there. /dev/video0
and something strange, when I give command to reboot the RPi 'sudo reboot', its just get shutdown, so i need to manually power it on again. earlier it wasn't like this.

Comment: try a new image - preferably bullseye not buster